# Extract result set from a execute sql task and store it in a excel file?

Tags: ssis, export-to-excel, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, execute-sql-task

I have a execute SQL task, that needs two input variables and a output variable to run. The SP returns a table that i'm storing in ResultSet parameter. I want to store the values in this ResultSet parameter in a excel file.
From my internet research([similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57821558), [Export data from SQL Server to Excel](https://codingsight.com/export-data-from-sql-server-to-excel-and-text-file-via-using-ssis-package/)), i found a few articles where they create a ADO.NET sources. Run a simple select query inside it and use excel destination. In my case, the parameters to SP have to be passed as variable.Hence, i can't use the harcoded SQL queries.
Can anyone please point me in the current direction? My knowledge of SSIS is very limited to be doing a good google search.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is in a data flow. Use a SQL Server source (you can use a question mark (?) as a placeholder to map variables) and an excel destination (although I would recommend csv). example select * from table where column = ?, Parameters are set in order of appearance in the sql

Comment: @KeithL would it work for `Exec [StoredprocedureName] ?, ? ? OUTPUT` as well. Also, do you have any link to help me with this?`code`

Answer (score 1):

If the question is, how to store values from ResultSet parameter to Excel, you have to create a custom data source:
https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/